# \hrulefill behavior with a tikz draw command

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I would like the dotted line drawn with **Tikz** below to `\hfill` like the `\hrulefill` line does.    Any ideas without using any external packages?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dottedLine}{m}{%
  \tikz \draw [blue, dotted, thick] (0,0) -- (#1,0);
}

\begin{document}
  Name: {\color{blue}\hrulefill} \quad Date: {\color{blue}\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}\par
  Name: \dottedLine{2in} \quad Date: {\color{blue}\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `tikz`, just replace `\hrulefill` with `\dotfill`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use TikZ for this? As Steven says, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want dots to act like `\hrulefill`, just use `\dotfill` in its stead.  There is no need for `tikz` in this case.  While I initially doubted that `tikz` could be made to "fill", Andrew Stacey (see comment) assured me that it could do so.

The dot spacing can be revised by redefining the default `.44em` spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  Name: {\color{blue}\dotfill} \quad Date: {\color{blue}\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}\par

Change dot spacing to .33em
\makeatletter
\renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

  Name: {\color{blue}\dotfill} \quad Date: {\color{blue}\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course TikZ can be made to fill! `\tikzmark{a}\hfill\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[dotted] (pic cs:a) -- (0,0);`. But I agree that there's no need to overcomplicate it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you for correcting me on that point!

Comment: But just because it _can_ doesn't mean it _should_! Your solution is by far the simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes on possible solutions to this problem, and an example of why TikZ is of use.

Thank you to @StevenB.Segletes & @AndrewStacey for helpful advice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\newcommand\tikzname{Ti\emph{k}Z}
\newcommand\datePart{\quad Date: {\color{blue}\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Using |\hrulefill|:\par
      Name: {\color{blue}\hrulefill} \datePart
    \item
      Using |\dotfill|:\par
      Name: {\color{blue}\dotfill} \datePart
    \item 
      Using |\dotfill| with custom 0.25em spacing:\par
      \makeatletter
        \renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .25em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
      \makeatother
      Name: {\color{blue}\dotfill} \datePart
    \item 
      Using \tikzname\ to hfill line: \par
      Name: \tikzmark{a}\hfill\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[blue, dotted, thick] (pic cs:a) -- (0,0); \datePart
    \item 
      Using \tikzname\ to hfill rectangle: \\[8pt]   
      Name: \tikzmark{b}\hfill\tikz[rounded corners=4pt, remember picture, overlay] \draw [blue, thick, overlay] (0,12pt) rectangle ([shift={(0,-2pt)}]pic cs:b);  \datePart
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's a good example!