# How to draw a rule from current position to the right of text area?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want co create a custom command which allows me to draw a line from current position to the right of text area. This is similar to `\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}` except that the line width is determined until the rule reaches the right of text area

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\widthWidest}
\setlength{\widthWidest}{\widthof{Text }}

\usepackage{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD
    
    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=true}
    \geometry{inner=10mm, outer=10mm, includemp=false}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ruletoright}[1]{%
    \tikz[] {%
        %
        \draw [color=red, line width=#1]
            (0, 0)
            --
            (\dimexpr \textwidth - \widthWidest + 1pt \relax, 0);
        %
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent%
    \smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
    Text \ruletoright{0.1pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is basically like [Q666035](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/666035) without anything on the end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just TeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\geometry{
  a6paper,% just to have a smaller picture
  twoside=false,
  showframe=true,
  inner=10mm,
  outer=10mm,
  includemp=false
}

\newcommand{\ruletoright}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
  \color{red}%
  \leaders\hrule height #1\hfill\null
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\noindent    
Text\ruletoright{1pt}% to better see it

\noindent
Other text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution does not work when using `\smash` and `\rlap`, `\llap`

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Sorry, but I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Placing `\ruletoright` inside the arguments of `\smash` and `\rlap`, `\llap` produces no output

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh That's true, but what would be the use case?

Comment: I want to produce such lines to debug and verify alignments in codes

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh So you were asking an XY-question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need special lines, @egreg's non-tikz solution is probably best. If you do need special lines, here is a `tikz` solution.

The command `\ruletoright[<tikz options>]` can be placed anywhere in a document (even in the middle of a line) and will draw the desired line using the `current page text area` node provided by the package `tikzpagenodes`.

Options include color, line style, thickness, etc. You can also include more than one line with different styles (use shift).

You must compile twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\ruletoright}[1][]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, #1]
    {\node(A){};\draw(A.center)--(A-|current page text area.east);}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\lipsum[1][1]\ruletoright[red, very thick]\ruletoright[red, very thick]

\noindent\lipsum[1][5]\ruletoright[blue, thick, dashed, yshift=1mm]

\noindent\lipsum[1][6]\ruletoright[blue, semithick, yshift=1mm]\ruletoright[red, semithick]

\noindent\lipsum[1][3]\ruletoright[orange, very thick] \lipsum[1][4]\ruletoright[yshift=.5ex, thick, ->]

\end{document}
```